# Glide load quality photo depending on size of imageview [low if size small(icon)]

Tags: android

I know this kind question has been aroud but I'm having a specific issue ..
I'm using a `glide library` to transform image path in my `sqlite database` to `imageview`in my`expendablelistview`..and i'm using `photoview library` to make them zoomable ..the problem is the size of imageviw determine the quality of loaded images ..let me explain:

if the imageview is big then the loaded image is big and in zomming looks good. but if the imageview is small(let's say icon) ..then the loaded quality is bad and when zooming looks really bad.

i want to make a small imageview but when clicked get good quality image zoomable

This is my code:

```
case R.id.child3 :
    ImageView url = (ImageView) view;
    String urls;
    urls = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_3));
    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(urls).into(url);
    url.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_layout, null);
            PhotoView photoView = mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                photoView.setImageDrawable(((ImageView)view).getDrawable());
            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
            mDialog.show();
        }
    });
    break;
```

My list_child.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/child3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Dialog_custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Solved with adding noTransformation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with adding noTransformation:

```
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(urls).apply(noTransformation()).into(url);
```

and

```
public static RequestOptions noTransformation() {
        if (noTransformOptions == null) {
            noTransformOptions = new RequestOptions()
                    .dontTransform()
                    .autoClone();
        }
        return noTransformOptions;
    }
```